# After restarting my computer when i again run "npm start" for React project it shows following ERROR! Help me out

Tags: reactjs, npm

Starting the development server...

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/user_name/chat-app/public'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:218:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1525:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/user_name/chat-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/user_name/chat-app/public',
  filename: '/home/user_name/chat-app/public'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chat-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the chat-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user_name/.npm/_logs/2020-12-11T06_24_55_498Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Search on google `ENOSPC`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have multiple react projects open. Try to close other projects and test again. This happens because your changes on the project are watched on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

"Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC)#
[Check here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc)
When you see this notification, it indicates that the VS Code file watcher is running out of handles because the workspace is large and contains many files. The current limit can be viewed by running:

cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
The limit can be increased to its maximum by editing /etc/sysctl.conf (except on Arch Linux, read below) and adding this line to the end of the file:

fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
The new value can then be loaded in by running sudo sysctl -p.

While 524,288 is the maximum number of files that can be watched, if you're in an environment that is particularly memory constrained, you may wish to lower the number. Each file watch takes up 1080 bytes, so assuming that all 524,288 watches are consumed, that results in an upper bound of around 540 MiB.

Arch-based distros (including Manjaro) require you to change a different file; follow these steps instead.